# Not running query even tho Im sending the values in ASP

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-update

Im running an update query, it says it is not finding the second parameter (status), although I am clearly sending it. They are in different classes and are being called by a button which sends a mail and then changes the value of a variable (statusRef) in the main table (this field is new).

```
    protected void sendMail(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BO.Messages mail = new BO.Messages();
        string body = "Cuerpo Mensaje";
        string title = "Titulo";
        string script = "alert(\"An email has been sent to the candidate! \");";
        mail.refEmail(emailCandi.Text,title,body);
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                              "ServerControlScript", script, true);
        Email_Sent.Visible = true;
        changeRefStatus(Int32.Parse(idCand.Text), "1");           
    }

    protected void changeRefStatus(int id, string status)
    {
        ASF.HC.JobApplication.BO.User u = new ASF.HC.JobApplication.BO.User();
        u.saveStatusRef(id,status);


    }

    public int saveStatusRef(int id, string status)
    {
        Entity.User u = new Entity.User();
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("dbo.[user_saveStatusRef]", base.Db);
        SqlParameter spSearch = new SqlParameter("@id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter spSearch2 = new SqlParameter("@status", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
        spSearch.Value = id;
        spSearch.Value = status;
        comando.Parameters.Add(spSearch);
        comando.Parameters.Add(spSearch2);
        return base.ExecuteScalar(comando);
    }
```

The stored procedure...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.user_saveStatusRef 
@id int,
@status varchar(5)
AS
UPDATE tbl_user
set statusRef = @status
WHERE id = @id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a typo but you dont assign Value to `spSearch2`

```
    spSearch.Value = id;
    spSearch.Value = status;
```

Comment: Nice catch! That would explain why it's not finding the second parameter.

Comment: My god! What a good eye. That worked just fine, but now I am getting an exception (although it did change the value). This message: 

An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ASF.HC.JobApplication.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I dont know if it is a wise advice just to handle the exception or change anything else.....

Comment: what line give you the exception? You should use `ExecuteNoQuery`... `ExecuteScalar` is for things like `COUNT(*)` where is just one value.

Comment: protected int ExecuteScalar(SqlCommand comando)
        {
            comando.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Db.Open();
            int rowCount = 0;
            bool executionValid = int.TryParse(comando.ExecuteScalar().ToString(), out rowCount);   <---- Where it is counting rows..
            Db.Close();
            return rowCount;
        }

Comment: not sure if make any difference but try `comando.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: not quite. added a catcher for the exception, and behaviour seems normal. Thanks for everything!

Comment: You should look deeper, I dont see any reason for that Null exception.